# Accessing Polygons of Dissolved Layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, dissolve

I've been trying to access the polygons of a dissolved layer in QGIS, and every time I query them, I get an empty polygon back. My procedure is as follows:

1. I start with a layer of polygons, and use the dissolve feature to dissolve some of them (this is not a problem, and the layer is generated, and I can see it, highlight it, and interact with its features)
2. In the python console, I find a feature in this layer, and type:

   ```
   feature.geometry().asPolygon()
   ```

   which returns

   ```
   []
   ```

   even though I can highlight it in the map interface.

Am I misunderstanding the scope of the asPolygon() function?

---

I figured out my mistake! To all future readers: the dissolve function may output multiple polygons as a single feature, meaning that they are a multipolygon, not a polygon. Thus, the function that should be called is geometry().asMultiPolygon() to return the co-ordinates.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _"access the polygons"_ please? Do you just want to [return the geometry](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a0a22b9d9318407864a28627f7243fd30) of the selected polygon(s)?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to see. Normally when I apply asPolygon() to a feature, I get a list of co-ordinates for the boundary, but here I only get an empty list.

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/245778/edit) your question to include the full code you used? The `asPolygon()` method seems to work fine for me.